# Avoid iframe-busting with nwdisable and nwfaketop?

Tags: javascript, iframe

So, I followed this tutorial on [How to create cross-platform desktop apps with NW.js](http://blog.aluxian.com/how-to-create-cross-platform-desktop-apps-with-nw-js/) because apparently you can insert any website inside an iframe, you can login and the iframe will not break, but it doesn't work, it only works with one example on the duck searcher, can anyone tell me how can I prevent the iframe-busting with the nwjs tool?
Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/Aluxian/nwjs-starter) with the full project

Answer (score 0):

Set these two attributes and everything will be framed including this site:

> FrameID.setAttribute('nwdisable','true');
>   FrameID.setAttribute('nwfaketop','true');

There's no escape from this because it gives the "victim" site a fake top value.

End of story.